# Main section appears weirdly on wordpress with elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, optimization, shortcode, elementor

i have been having some issues displaying pages properly on the website i'm working,

since an exemple is worth a thousand explanation go visit that web page and you'll see that the main section appears weirdly https://www.lannuaire.fr/0645325643/ .

I've made it dynamic by using this code and calling this function with a shortcode on the page,

the template that it loads is the whole blue section,

```
public function affiche_tel_non_trouve ()   
                                                    
        {
            $tel = get_query_var('tel');
            $suffixe = $tel[1] ;
            
            if (isset($suffixe) && $suffixe != '6' && $suffixe != '7') {                    
                echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="2021"]');

            } else if ($suffixe == '6' || $suffixe == '7') {                                      
                echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="2266"]');
            }
        }
```

I've been searching why I have this problem for too long I now am out of clue, I suspect that it is an optimization problem,

so now i seek help, to know why is that happening.

Thank you for your time

(Sorry for the approximate english)

i've also tried loading only the white section since it is the important part but it won't solve the problem, also this display problem doesn't appear using firefox and it is less visible on opera (i'm using chrome).

Comment: I'm not sure what is "Weird" about your page. What is it doing that you don't like? It's not apparent.

Comment: At the very start of the page, you can see kind of like every border on the section kind of flashing before it appears well.